# How to get average cumulative value for several columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, average

Microsoft SQL Server 2019

Table example:

| name | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test1 | 43 | -3 | NULL | NULL |
| test2 | 35 | 33 | NULL | NULL |
| test3 | 32 | 35 | 21 | NULL |
| test4 | 32 | 39 | NULL | NULL |
| test5 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| test6 | 18 | -20 | 37 | NULL |
| test7 | NULL | 14 | NULL | NULL |
| test8 | 57 | 60 | NULL | NULL |

I need to get an output table like:

| mean12 | mean123 | mean1234 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 29 | 29 |

Where mean12 = rounded average from all not NULL values of columns Q1 and Q2.

It counts according to this logic:

```
ROUND((ROUND((43+35+32+32+18+57)/6) + ROUND((-3+33+35+39-20+14+60)/7))/2) = 
ROUND((ROUND(36.16) + ROUND(22.57))/2) =
ROUND((36+23)/2) = ROUND(29.5) = 30
```

The rounded average of each column is counted first, and then the rounded average between them.

mean123 = rounded average from all not NULL values of columns Q1, Q2 and Q3;

mean1234 = rounded average from all not NULL values of columns Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4

I tried to do it like

```
SELECT 
    ROUND(((ROUND(AVG(Q1), 0) + ROUND(AVG(Q2), 0)) / 2), 0) AS Mean12,
    ROUND(((ROUND(AVG(Q1), 0) + ROUND(AVG(Q2), 0) + ROUND(AVG(Q3), 0)) / 3), 0) AS +Mean123,
    ROUND(((ROUND(AVG(Q1), 0) + ROUND(AVG(Q2), 0) + ROUND(AVG(Q3), 0) + ROUND(AVG(Q4), 0)) / 4), 0) AS Mean1234
```

but it is not working correctly, because of NULLs in column Q4:

| mean12 | mean123 | mean1234 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 29 | NULL |

I can't figure out how to get the average in any other way. Help me please!

```
CREATE TABLE test(
   name VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY
  ,Q1   INTEGER 
  ,Q2   INTEGER 
  ,Q3   INTEGER 
  ,Q4   INT 
);
INSERT INTO test(name,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4) VALUES
 ('test1',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
,('test2',43,-3,NULL,NULL)
,('test3',35,33,NULL,NULL)
,('test5',32,39,NULL,NULL)
,('test6',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
,('test7',18,-20,37,NULL)
,('test8',NULL,14,NULL,NULL)
,('test9',57,60,NULL,NULL);
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Thank you for the comment, I added to the question.

Comment: How do you want to handle NULLs? As 0? Or exclude them from the calculation? You'll get different results in each case. A missing measurement isn't the same as a measurement with value 0

Comment: Instead of adding expressions that can return a NULL, use `COALESCE(thatExpression,0)` to replace NULL with 0. This means you need to wrap each `ROUND` expression with `COALESCE()`

Comment: How are the quarter values calculated in the first place? It's easier to handle NULLs if the data is in "long" form, ie before quarter values become columns.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in this case, I need to ignore nulls in the calculation

Comment: `AVG` already does that. That's why I said it would be easier to calculate it *before* converting quarter amounts into columns. The answer converts the data to long form, calculates the running average, then converts it back to wide form. You can't ignore NULLs in math operations though, you need to actually specify an alternative. In addition, that's typically `0`. In multiplication, it's `1`. That's done using `COALESCE()`

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

It is using a row value constructor approach.

It is excluding NULL values from the calculations.

**SQL #1**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (name VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY, Q1 INT, Q2 INT, Q3 INT, Q4 INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl (name, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4) VALUES
('test1', 43,   -3,   NULL, NULL),
('test2', 35,   33,   NULL, NULL),
('test3', 32,   35,   21,   NULL),
('test4', 32,   39,   NULL, NULL),
('test5', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
('test6', 18,   -20,    37, NULL),
('test7', NULL, 14,   NULL, NULL),
('test8', 57,   60,   NULL, NULL);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT mean12 = AVG(mean12), mean123 = AVG(mean123), mean1234 = AVG(mean1234)
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES 
         (t.Q1),
         (t.Q2)
         ) AS t1(mean12)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES 
         (t.Q1),
         (t.Q2),
         (t.Q3)
         ) AS t2(mean123)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES 
         (t.Q1),
         (t.Q2),
         (t.Q3),
         (t.Q4)
         ) AS t3(mean1234);
```

**Output**

| mean12 | mean123 | mean1234 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 28 | 28 | 28 |

**SQL #2**

```
;WITH rs AS
(        
    SELECT mean1 = AVG(Q1), mean2 = AVG(Q2), mean3 = AVG(Q3), mean4 = AVG(Q4) 
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT Mean12 = (mean1 + mean2) / 2
    , Mean123 = (mean1 + mean2 + mean3) / 3
    , Mean1234 = (mean1 + mean2 + mean3 + COALESCE(mean4, 0)) / (3 + IIF(mean4 IS NULL,0,1))
FROM rs;
```

**Output**

| Mean12 | Mean123 | Mean1234 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 29 | 29 | 29 |

Comment: `AVG` already excludes NULLs. The problem is that all Q4 values are null so `AVG(Q4)` is NULL. Adding it to the other expressions returns NULL in turn

Comment: That's why I didn't use `WHERE t1.mean12 IS NOT NULL`, etc.

Comment: So you're UNpivoting the values with `VALUES` then repivoting it with CROSS APPLY. That's better than trying to handle the nulls themselves

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky It looks nice, but the output is not what I would like. On this data mean12 should be 30, mean123=mean1234=29

Comment: This is because the average value is calculated immediately by combining two columns, but in my case we need to calculate the average for each and the average between the values obtained.

Comment: I added SQL #2. It is much closer to your logic. You can tinker with it to get a desired output.

Comment: Thank you very much, I combined both of your solutions and got exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

By combining the solutions suggested above, I achieved exactly the logic I needed:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(AvQ1 Float, AvQ2 Float, AvQ3 Float, AvQ4 Float);
    INSERT INTO @table
    SELECT ROUND(AVG(QVPM1), 0), ROUND(AVG(QVPM2), 0), ROUND(AVG(QVPM3), 0),  ROUND(AVG(QVPM4), 0) FROM @test
    
    SELECT mean12 = ROUND(AVG(mean12), 0), mean123 = ROUND(AVG(mean123), 0), mean1234 = ROUND(AVG(mean1234), 0)
    FROM @table AS t
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES 
             (t.AvQ1),
             (t.AvQ2)
             ) AS t1(mean12)
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES 
             (t.AvQ1),
             (t.AvQ2),
             (t.AvQ3)
             ) AS t2(mean123)
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES 
             (t.AvQ1),
             (t.AvQ2),
             (t.AvQ3),
             (t.AvQ4)
             ) AS t3(mean1234);
```